# How to store integers to Firestore with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store multiple datatypes in Firebase including Int datatype but when storing Integers to Firebase it doesn't  store the value that I set it using SetState function.

I've tried to use If-Statement before storing the value to Database,Nothing changed.

```
int itemBarcode;
int itemBonusQTY=0;
int itemCostPrice=0;
```

```
Future<void> addData(productsData) async {
  Firestore.instance.collection('Products').add(productsData).catchError((e) 
{
print(e);
});}

Future toDataBase(BuildContext context) async {
 addData({
    'ItemBarcode': this.itemBarcode,
    'BonusQTY': this.itemBonusQTY,
    'CostPrice': this.itemCostPrice
 }).then((result) {
 }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
 });
}
```

```
Future addDialog(BuildContext context)  async {
await showDialog(

TextField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
   onChanged: (value) {
    this.itemBarcode = value as int;
},

TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
   onChanged: (value) {
   if (itemBonusQTY != null) {
      this.itemBonusQTY = value as int;
 } else {
   setState(() {
    itemBonusQTY = 0;
 });}
 },)

TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
   onChanged: (value) {
  if (itemCostPrice!= null) {
     this.itemCostPrice= value as int;
 } else {
   setState(() {
    itemCostPrice= 0;
 });}
 },)
```

```
FlatButton(
 child: Text('Add'),
 textColor: Colors.amber,
 onPressed: () {
   toDataBase(context);
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
},
 ),

Output in DB 
    itemBarcode = null
    itemBonusQTY = 0
    itemCostPrice = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store like this

```
Future toDataBase(BuildContext context) async {
 addData({
    'ItemBarcode': int.parse(this.itemBarcode),
    'BonusQTY': int.parse(this.itemBonusQTY),
    'CostPrice': int.parse(this.itemCostPrice)
 }).then((result) {
 }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
 });
}
```